# how to set http header with AFClient

Tags: ios, http-headers, afnetworking

how to set http headers by using AFClient, in code below, where should i set the headers?

i know AFHTTPClient can set http headers. the sample code AFNetworking gives is below:

AFAppDotNetAPIClient.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface AFAppDotNetAPIClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (AFAppDotNetAPIClient *)sharedClient;

@end
```

AFAppDotNetAPIClient.m

```
#import "AFAppDotNetAPIClient.h"

#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

static NSString * const kAFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString = @"https://alpha-api.app.net/";

@implementation AFAppDotNetAPIClient

+ (AFAppDotNetAPIClient *)sharedClient {
    static AFAppDotNetAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[AFAppDotNetAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you would place them under the

`[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];`

But that begs the question [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: honestly， i come up empty， thnx for ur quick response